# How to include categorical variables in pooled OLS using plm()?

Tags: r, lm, categorical-data, plm

Is there a way to include categorical variables (factors with several factor levels) when using `plm()` for pooled OLS? As far as I understand, in `plm()` all variables have to be numeric, which will not work in my case. I could include one dummy variable for each factor level, however, this would lead to a larger number of variables which actually are only levels of considerably fewer factors.

I've posed a similar question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133508/how-does-turning-categorical-variables-into-dummy-variables-affect-anova-results) and would be thankful for any kind of help.

I will include a minimal example if requested, but I assume this is more a general question on how to use `plm()` and `lm()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily include both numeric and  categorical variables variables in both `plm()` and `lm()`.

```
require(plm)
data(Males)
head(Males[1:6])
# nr year school exper union  ethn
# 1 13 1980     14     1    no other
# 2 13 1981     14     2   yes other
# 3 13 1982     14     3    no other
# 4 13 1983     14     4    no other
# 5 13 1984     14     5    no other
# 6 13 1985     14     6    no other

coef(lm(wage ~ school + union + ethn, data=Males))
# (Intercept)      school    unionyes   ethnblack    ethnhisp 
# 0.7148      0.0767      0.1930     -0.1523      0.0134 

coef(plm(wage ~ school + union + ethn, data=Males, model="pooling"))
# (Intercept)      school    unionyes   ethnblack    ethnhisp 
# 0.7148      0.0767      0.1930     -0.1523      0.0134
```

As you can see, you can have both dummy and categorical variables in both instances.

Comment: Thank you. I've read somewhere that it would not work and I used to get an error message when including factors, but obviously the problem was something else...

Comment: I would suspect that you're hitting your head against factor contrasts. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445316/factors-in-r-more-than-an-annoyance and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352617/how-and-why-do-you-use-contrasts-in-r.